# How to Convert 2022-02-08T09:34:35.000Z this date and time into dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm;ss in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, time

I am getting 2022-02-08T09:34:35.000Z this response from an API.

I am trying to convert it into a simple format like- 08-02-2022 09:34:35

Comment: https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Date.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

```
let date = new Date();
date = date.toLocaleString()
```

Comment: If this is ran in the US the result would be 02-08-2022 not what the OP wants.

Comment: In fact, no, it wouldn't even be that it'd be `02/08/2022`, so this is **totally** wrong

Comment: @Liam I understand that if that is what he receives from the server he is getting it on the client. And this would return '2/8/2022, 12:08:34 PM'. What you mean is toLocaleDateString()

Comment: *I am trying to convert it into a simple format like- 08-02-2022 09:34:35* `2/8/2022, 12:08:34 PM` is not `08-02-2022 09:34:35`